# Rails 3 - Solr doesn't search an items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

In the **Photo** model I have following simple rule:

```
  searchable do
    string :note
  end
```

and I try to search some string with **Solr** (simultaneously in two tables). This is the output of **Solr query** in the terminal (the first one for **Articles**, the second one for **Photos**):

> SOLR Request (4.8ms)  [ path=# parameters={data: fq=type%3A
>   **Article&q=searched_string&fl=%2A+score&qf=title+content&defType=dismax&start=0&rows=30** , method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, headers:
>   {"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"},
>   path: select, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/select?wt=ruby,
>   open_timeout: , read_timeout: } ]

and this

> SOLR Request (4.4ms)  [ path=#
>   parameters={data: fq=type%3A
>   **Photo&q=asgasg&fl=%2A+score&defType=dismax&start=0&rows=30** , method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, headers:
>   {"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"},
>   path: select, uri: http://localhost:8982/solr/select?wt=ruby,
>   open_timeout: , read_timeout: } ]

controller:

```
@articles = Article.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
end
@photos = Photo.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
end
## => searching ##
puts @articles.results #work fine
puts @photos.results #always 0
```

I totally don't know, why SOLR doesn't search in the **Photo** model... everything should be specified and set up, but still don't know, where is the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in Photo model you have to define `:note` as `text` type (not `string`) in order to run fulltext search on it:

```
searchable do
  text :note
end
```

Also, you set `@articles` and `@photos`, but checking `@users` and `@photos` in your question.

*UPDATE*

According to [sunspot readme](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot):

"text fields will be full-text searchable. Other fields (e.g., integer and string) can be used to scope queries"

That is, to run `fulltext` or `keywords` on that field, it has to be declared as `text` *in the searchable block*. You have it as `string`, which can only be used for exact match using `with()`.

Good luck.

Comment: `note` is `varchar(255)`, instead of using `fulltext` I tried to use there `keywords`, but still nothing.

Comment: Thank for your help, Simon. I posted the solution in the separately post. Well... I tried also to use string with `with` clausule, but that didn't work me... I try to search on text/string column, and it's working well without the set up of `with` part. It looks there is always needed to reindex SOLR, if are made some changes in the `searchable` part in the model...

Answer (score 0):

The working solution of my problem:
1. stop the rails server
2. rake sunspot:reindex
3. run the rails server

If is everything changed in the `searchable` block, then is needed to reindex data.